# org.apache.camel:camel-maven-plugin is missing (Windows 10)

Tags: java, apache, maven, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ I can see this image:
[image]

And when I try to run my program I see this error:

> [WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective
>   model for
>   com.domain.subdomain:06-sprint-currency-route:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
>   [WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for
>   org.apache.camel:camel-maven-plugin is missing. @ line 75, column 21

My Pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.domain.subdomain</groupId>
    <artifactId>06-sprint-currency-route</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>spi-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-jms -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-http4</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.activemq/activemq-all -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
            <version>5.15.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Allows the routes to be run via 'mvn camel:run' -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: You have to define the version of the plugin...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warning

> 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.camel:camel-maven-plugin is missing

means, that **'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.camel:camel-maven-plugin is missing.**

So add

```
<version>2.20.0</version>
```

into your **build.plugins.plugin** section in pom.